# Error installing software "cannot locate microsoft visual foxpro support library windows xp"

Tags: installation, windows-installer, foxpro, visual-foxpro

When I try to install software on my Windows XP machine, it is looking for Microsoft Visual foxpro support libraries, and I'm getting this error:

> cannot locate microsoft visual foxpro support library.

Googled and got some suggestions which did not help.

Tried putting `msvcr70.dll`, `vfp7r.dll`, `vfp8renu.dll` in the installation folder.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I believe this error is usually caused by the compiled application having the wrong version of the runtimes(DLLs). Below are links that show what runtimes(DLLs) need to be distributed with the compiled application version.

You mention both VFP7 and VFP8. You'll need to know what version of VFP the application was compiled in and copy the correct runtimes to this application folder. Or at least try one set of runtimes and then the other to see which works.

http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFP9RuntimeFiles
http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFP8RuntimeFiles
http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFP7RuntimeFiles